# How can one prevent variable substitution/expension in AWS Fargate container definition command

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, docker-run

Locally when running docker with `docker run` I pass some arguments like:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 -e "SERVICE_B_URL=somehost.co.uk" -d mynginx:latest /bin/sh -c "envsubst '\${SERVICE_B_URL}' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

This works fine. In my `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` the string `${SERVICE_B_URL}` is replaced with `somehost.co.uk`.

When running on AWS fargate with a definition like:

```
"environment": [
        {
          "name": "SERVICE_B_URL",
          "value": "someotherhost.co.uk"
        }
      ],
"command": [
        "/bin/sh",
        "-c",
        "envsubst '\\${SERVICE_B_URL}' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
      ],
```

The `\\` was to escape the `\` in the JSON file.

When trying to run, the container exits with an error because NGINX is seeing the literal string `${SERVICE_B_URL}`. When I inspect the container and see the command AWS used to start the container it is:

```
Command ["/bin/sh","-c","envsubst '\\' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

Notice that Fargate has attempted to expand the string `'\\${SERVICE_B_URL}'` before supplying it as a command to docker run. My intention is to specify that as a literal string.

Is there a way to escape this/stop expansion. I've tried things like `'\\\\${SERVICE_B_URL}'` -> `'\\'`.

---

Footnote, if you are wondering why I specify the `'\${SERVICE_B_URL}'` to `envsubst` instead of just using:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 -e "SERVICE_B_URL=somehost.co.uk" -d mynginx:latest /bin/sh -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

The reason is, that the file being substituted contains other NGINX configuration which makes use of variables with `$` syntax. So to prevent these being replaced by `envsubst` I explicitly name the variable I want to be replaced. Running locally with docker run, it works like a charm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up simplifying this by making the command we would pass to `docker run` part of the `Dockerfile` itself using `CMD`, e.g:

```
CMD ["/bin/sh","-c","envsubst '\\${SERVICE_B_URL}' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

Now we can remove the `command` configuration from the JSON file for Fargate.